# O uso de "você" no Brasil é um vício de linguagem?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

O você em Portugal é usado como sujeito oculto pelo que tenho visto em Lisboa, Coimbra e Porto, além dos médias. Fala-se assim: "Agora que leu o termo de contrato, (você) deve assinar na linha pontilhada. Isto implica que (você) concorda com os termos no presente documento".

Outra variação é o pronome do discurso indireto "si" no lugar de você:"Esta prenda é para si", "trazemos o melhor da notícia para si". No Brasil, usa-se o "si" precedido de um verbo no imperativo: "guarde para si", "faça isto para si".

O caso do uso do você no Brasil já está impregnado a nível vicioso? o voceísmo, que é a afirmação do verbo como ato praticado pela segunda pessoa, numa construção bizarra: "você me conhece", "Agora você tem a mitigação e a quarentena vertical e você tem a horizontal, você opta pela horizontal" (você ou as pessoas tomadoras de decisão)?

"Na segurança pública, você (eu ou o agente da lei?) deve optar por soluções pacíficas, que protejam a vida humana. Você (eu?) só deve usar a força quando você (eu?) vir que estão esgotadas as possibilidades de controle não-violentas".

> — Bem, aaah..., você tem que dar mais educação aaah... para o povo, aaah..., não basta você apenas aaah... você reforçar o aparelhamento de segurança pública, aaah..., porque senão você cai num aaah..., círculo vicioso aaah..., e aí, aaah..., você permanece com os problemas, você continua com eles aaah..., só que aaah... mais agravados. Você sabe, né, aaah... educação é a base de tudo...

Este uso disseminado do você, como o "a gente" em lugar da primeira pessoa do plural todas as vezes, não seria um vício de linguagem ao nível do gerundismo?

Fontes:

- http://voceismo.blogspot.com/2011/04/voceismo.html
- https://sognarelucido.wordpress.com/2019/04/26/clinica-de-voceismo-depois-do-gerundismo-e-queismo/

Comment: Em Portugal tu fazes isso com o *tu*. Agora, não sei é se vais conseguir dar uma resposta minimamente objetiva a esta pergunta.

Comment: É como diz o Jacinto: em Portugal é o *sujeito* que é oculto; não o você especificamente.

Comment: https://dicionario.priberam.org/v%C3%ADcio vício?? Acho que esta é uma pergunta ridícula, pessoalmente. gerundismo e você, poco tem a ver.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Contudo, meu pensamento tem direção oposta ao relativismo linguistico. Eu creio que o uso exagerado do você em lugar do discurso indireto e na 3a pessoa está ao mesmo pé do gerundismo e do agentismo e empobrecem o idioma pois diminuem as conjugações verbais. Enfim, é o que acho. Obrigado e até mais ver.

Comment: Lambie, acho que quis dizer " pouco". Se aceita-se gerundismo, porquê o preconceito com o voceísmo?

Answer (score -1):

'O Português do Brasil usa o pronome pessoal você, quer para designar a 2.ª, quer a 3.ª pessoa do singular, correspondentes ao tu e ele/a do Português Europeu. É uma forma de tratamento muito comum no Brasil' na forma informal.

Comment: Acho que não é exatamente isso. O pronome você é usado para designar sempre a 2ª pessoa do singular, porém para fins de conjugações utiliza-se a 3ª pessoa do singular.

Answer (score -1):

Sugerir que o uso natural de um idioma, em determinada região ,possa ser um vício de linguagem é uma abordagem incorreta sob o ponto de vista linguístico, uma vez que parte-se do princípio de que determinada norma é a correta em detrimento de outra. O uso do "você" reflete pura e simplesmente a utilização natural do idioma no Brasil.

Comment: Então, do ponto de vista linguístico, não é um vício de linguagem o uso da palavra "[literally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally)" com o sentido metafórico de "metafórico" (o seu oposto)? Custa-me a crer. "Alegações extraordinárias requerem evidências extraordinárias", podes fundamentar a tua resposta?